# is it possible to create a docker image that creates and runs another docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need a machine that runs Kali OS, and builds and runs some docker container.
This was easy using Virtual box.
But it was proved hard (impossible?) on docker.
So - I want to create an image, based on Kali, and then build and run some docker container. is this possible?

I wrote something like this:

```
FROM kalilinux/kali-rolling
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y git
RUN apt install -y docker.io
RUN git clone https://something
RUN docker build . -f /something/Dockerfile  -t my_app
CMD docker run my_app
```

Comment: Docker isn't virtualization like VirtualBox. Docker is mainly for isolating a single process. There is a concept called docker-in-docker though, where you build an image in a container, but you put it in a repo outside the container and you also run it outside the container.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If I wanted a Kali machine that runs sql server e.g. - I can create such a docker image. why cann't I do the same with a docker image?

Comment: Usually, with Docker, if you want to run a web server with a database, you'd create 2 containers. One for the web server and one for the database. If I understand your question correctly, you want to run a container where you create new images and run them on a nested docker inside the container? You *can* run multiple processes in a Docker container. But if you want to run multiple processes, you should use a VM, imo.

Comment: The technique is called "docker in docker" (or dind) and is used in several CI tools (like in gitlab-ci runners). Just enter those terms in your favorite search engine for more info (there a few prereqs to fulfill). There is a [specific image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/?tab=tags) provided by the official docker team (look for all `dind*` tags). Note 1: You should only use this for ci/build/testing and not for production. Note 2: as already stated in several comments, I don't think there is any added value in your specific case.

Comment: Even if you do have a DinD setup, you can't `RUN docker ...` inside the Dockerfile (`RUN git clone` is also less reliable than you might hope).  The architecture you're suggesting here also won't work, in that if you `docker push` the image this builds to a registry and `docker pull` it on another system, that other system won't have the second image.  I think you have a layer of Docker too many; you just want to run `docker` commands directly on the host.

Answer (score 0):

A docker is a process (container) running on some environment, most probably on a local docker VM in your case. If you want to build another docker on that VM you need to install docker on it which is probably heavy cumbersome and not advisable.
If you want a Kali image (for some obscure reason) you can use ready made images.
[Here](https://www.kali.org/docs/containers/official-kalilinux-docker-images/)

No need to create another docker.

I would suggest you read up and take a docker tutorial.